# How to use "foreach" in combobox

Tags: c#

I Was trying to do keyword filter with textbox for combobox and I created something like this:

```
  private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textbox1.Text != null)
        {
            foreach(string item in combobox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Contains(textbox1.Text))
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Add(item);

                }
                else
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but I got "System.InvalidOperationException" "Anyone have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: You're iterating over items in `combobox1` and you're changing this collection during iteration. This is not allowed. A possible workarround might be `foreach (var item in combobox1.Items.ToList())`. I would prefer to find all items that has to be added and removed in a separate step.

Comment: Please keep in mind that you add `item` to `combobox1` which is already part of this collection. Are you sure that this is what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a collection and at the same time trying to change the collection; this is an invalid operation (hence the exception).

What you can do, however, is loop through a collection backwards like this:

```
for (int i = combobox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (combobox1.Items[i].ToString.Contains(textbox1.Text))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Also, this is going to add a duplicate to `combobox1`:

```
if (item.Contains(textbox1.Text))
{
    combobox1.Items.Add(item);

}
```

Are you sure that's what you want to happen?

Answer (score -1):

When you are running this code:

```
foreach(string item in combobox1.Items)
{

}
```

The collection of items in combobox cannot be modified. So, when you attempt to edit the items like this:

```
foreach(string item in combobox1.Items)
{
    combobox1.Items.Add(item);
    // or
    combobox1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

This is cause a runtime error. Therefore, the real collections of items has to be stored somewhere else outside of the combobox. Below is one of the resolution.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 1500;
        timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;

        lst.Add("Red");
        lst.Add("Yellow");
        lst.Add("Blue");
    }

    void RefreshComboBox()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        if (textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            string txt = textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower();
            foreach (var str in lst)
            {
                if (str.ToLower().Contains(txt))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(str);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var str in lst)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(str);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        RefreshComboBox();
    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```